# Receive audio byte arrays with HTML5 Audio API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, streaming, html5-audio

I can broadcast or unicast (UDP) raw PCM data from microphone input, or the data encoded in G711 (MuLaw, ALaw) or Gsm10. This audio is thought to be played on a webpage. Flash and Silverlight cannot be used.

I'm currently investigating two solutions:
a) Client-side C# in ASP.NET (AJAX)
b) HTML5 Audio API

Is it theoretically possible to receive the byte arrays send with HTML5 Audio API and then play them on a homepage?

Answer (score 1):

Here provides an example to show you how the web audio API works

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

the response of request is the bytes array, then you can just follow the step on the web page.

Comment: This seems to work with files... does it also work with live streaming data?

Comment: Yes, where does your streaming bytes array come from?

Comment: I think you could find out the way to add more data into the array buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have an example with the best praticle to do it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wasm-ring-buffer,
but the UDP Websocket in the Client Side is enabled only in the Chrome Packaged APP. An alternative is create a Nodejs gateway to receive the data by TCP and sending it from your NodeJS server to your UDP server.